# Issue Copying and Deleting Arrays in C++

Tags: c++, delete-operator

I've been playing around with my own sockets and buffers lately.  For the following code, I have allocated a byte buffer within my class of size bufferSize.  The buffer is used as a wrap-around, and so I also track the front and back indices of the buffer.

In the code below, I allocate a local buffer that is the size of the class member buffer minus the data currently in the buffer, then read the socket data into it.  I then copy the local buffer into the class buffer using the front/back indices.

The code, as written, will print the expected data (I am sending test strings).  However, if I uncomment the delete[] on the local buffer, the data in the class buffer is deleted as well.  I have tried using memcpy and strcpy to copy the data from local to class buffer, to no avail.  However, this is an obvious memory leak if I never delete the local buffer.

I think I must be missing something obvious and stupid, but for the life of me I can't see what it is.

```
int readIntoBuffer(int timeout) {
    int lbufsize = bufferSize-bytesAvailable();

    byte *local_buffer = new byte[lbufsize+1];

    // read into the local buffer
    int bytes_read = socket->recv(local_buffer, lbufsize, timeout);

    // null-terminate the local buffer
    local_buffer[bytes_read] = '\0';

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes_read; i++) {
        // copy into class buffer, byte by byte
        buffer[bufferBack] = local_buffer[i];

        // update back index
        bufferBack = (bufferBack + 1) % bufferSize;
    }

    // null-terminator at current end of class buffer
    buffer[bufferBack] = '\0';

    //delete[] local_buffer;  

    std::cout << buffer+bufferFront << std::endl;

    return bytes_read;
}
```

Comment: `buffer[bufferBack] = local_buffer[i];`

Your assignment operator here is wrong, seemingly. Can you post the overloading of `=` in your byte class?

Comment: @erip That was my assuption, too, but I can't see how.  I've tried replacing it with equivalent memcpy and strcpy operations but it doesn't change the outcome.

Comment: Note that if recv() returns -1, you're going to write to local_buffer[-1] ...

Comment: Also, how does your string-printing code handle the case where the string is "wrapped", i.e. where the beginning of the string is at the end of (buffer), and the end of string is at the beginning of (buffer)?

Comment: I wrote the socket class myself.  It never returns less than 0,  the cout portion, as written, would cause the buffer to be truncated, but I just threw it in there to figure out what was happening.  Since this is the first recv into the buffer, and the string I sent is much smaller than the buffer, it isn't causing issues in this particular case.

Comment: @erip byte is just an unsigned char typedef, '=' operator is not overloaded

Comment: See my answer below.  It had nothing to do with this code at all, just stupidity on my part causing undefined behavior that decided to manifest itself here.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The real issue had nothing to do with my original question, it was simply sloppy pointer management on my part creating undefined behavior later in the code.

Basically, I incorrectly made use of a class member as a local referenced variable within another function.  Once the function exited, the class members were deleted as they went out of scope.  Fixing this problem has fixed the above issue.  Thanks to everyone for their input, sorry to have wasted your time with such a dumb mistake!